# How to store and retrieve image contents from the database using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have to store and retrieve an image from the database.
I want to store an image instead of image path or image name. When I searched for it I only found solutions for storing an image path or name. So can someone tell me how to store and retrieve an image with its size in KBs from database?

This is my route.

```
Route::get('big_image/{id}/image', function ($id)
{
   $user = big_image::find($id);
   return response()->make($user->image, 200, array(
   'Content-Type' => (new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME))->buffer($user->image)
));
```

});

This is my controller

```
 public  function new_store(Request $request ,$id){
    $event_id = $id;
    $img = new big_image;
    $file =  $request->file('image');
    $contents = $file->openFile()->fread($file->getSize());
    $img = big_image::find($id);
    $img->image = $contents;
    $img->image_name = $request->image_name;
    $img->event_id = $event_id;
    $img->save();
  $images=DB::table('big_image')->where('event_id','=',$event_id)->get();
  return view('image_upload',compact('images','id','response'));
}
```

My display.blade.php file

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
  <h2 style="text-align: center;margin-top: 10px;">Image Gallery</h2>
  <a href="{{url('pic_upload/'.$id.'')}}" class="col-sm-12"             style="padding-left: 0;"><span> add more pictures</span></a><br>
  <a href="{{url('events')}}"><span>Back to events</span></a><br>
   @foreach($images as $item)
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    {{--<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $item->image  ).'"/>;--}}
    </div>
@endforeach
@stop
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually with Laravel it only involves a few lines of code. Let's say you have a user that has an avatar which is stored in the database. Assuming you're using MySQL, here's how you would store and retrieve the avatar from the database:

**1.** First you'll need to have an `avatar` column in the `users` table that can store binary data. Depending on how large you want to allow the avatar image to be, the data type of the column can be one of the following:

> **BLOB** up to 64KB
>
> **MEDIUMBLOB** up to 16MB
>
> **LONGBLOB** up to 4GB

**2.** To store the uploaded image in the database you can do this:

```
Route::post('user/{id}', function (Request $request, $id) {
    // Get the file from the request
    $file = $request->file('image');

    // Get the contents of the file
    $contents = $file->openFile()->fread($file->getSize());

    // Store the contents to the database
    $user = App\User::find($id);
    $user->avatar = $contents;
    $user->save();
});
```

**3.** To fetch and ouput the avatar you can do the following:

```
Route::get('user/{id}/avatar', function ($id) {
    // Find the user
    $user = App\User::find(1);

    // Return the image in the response with the correct MIME type
    return response()->make($user->avatar, 200, array(
        'Content-Type' => (new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME))->buffer($user->avatar)
    ));
});
```

So to access the avatar of the user with an `id` equal to `10` you can just use this URL:

```
http://domain.com/user/10/avatar
```

Comment: I tried with your code but I got an image in this format 'G:\xampp\tmp\phpEA01.tmp'. So how can I solve this?And can you tell how can I use this with blade file?Because this is not working with display.blade.php file.

Comment: This code works, I've tested it before posting it as an answer. Please edit you question to include the code you're using at this moment.

Comment: I have edited my question.And I am getting an error for this line '$img->image = $contents;'.

Comment: So you're saying that the data stored in the `image` column is this `G:\xampp\tmp\phpEA01.tmp` and not binary data? And I assume you're trying to store a new `big_image` entry so you should remove the `$img = big_image::find($id);` line.

Comment: Yes.I am not getting binary data.Okay but I am getting this error 'Creating default object from empty value' because of '$img->image = $contents; line.So how should i resolve that?

Comment: But did you leave the `$img = new big_image;` when you removed the line with `big_image::find($id);`? Because that error means you don't have the `$img` variable initialised.

Comment: Yes.now error is gone.But image is not displayed on the page.It is showing nothng on the page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103607/discussion-between-shweta-and-bogdan).

Comment: Using this `<img src="{{url('big_image/' . $item->id . '/image')}}"/>` should suffice to display the image in your Blade view file.

Comment: Hi, this function works. But I am wondering, how to display the image in a standard size instead of having actual size uploaded? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store files in database in blob fields.

Maybe [this link](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/480731/how-to-inserting-files-on-mysql-using-laravel) helps you

Then You can create url to your image:

```
Route::get('/images/{image}', function($image)
{
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    //"select image from table where id = $image"
   echo $here_I_get_my_img_from_DB;
});
```

and get img from url: `/image/{img_id}`

Comment: I have stored an image in database and it is saved as [BLOB - 24 B] in database.Is it right way?And if it is right then i did not understand how to display it?

Comment: Okay.But how should I write this in my display.blade.php.Because I am displaying an image from this page.

Comment: Using this <img src="{{url('/image/' . $item->id )}}"/>

Comment: How to resize the image as standard size in blade?