# Getting Images from database using Laravel5

Tags: php, database, laravel, controller

I tried to display images uploaded in database using this:

image.blade.php

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <h1>Images:</h1> 
   {{Form::open(array('action' => 'ImageController@store','files'=>true))}}
   Title: {{Form::text('title')}}
   Image: {{Form::file('image')}}
   {{Form::submit('submit')}}
   {{Form::close()}}
   {{App::make("ImageController")->show() }} //error here
</div>
```

and here is the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Models\Image;

class ImageController extends Controller
{
  //smaple code.... show etc
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/upload','ImageController@index');
Route::post('/upload', 'ImageController@store');
Route::resource('img', 'ImageController');
```

I am getting this error in image.blade.php file:

Class ImageController does not exist:

I want to display all the images in database on view.
I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You probably to namespace the action call. `'action' => 'App\Http\Controllers\ImageController@store'` - and same thing for the `App::make()` call.

Comment: Do i have to make any changes in routes too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store and retrieve image contents from the database using Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428876/how-to-store-and-retrieve-image-contents-from-the-database-using-laravel)