# storing uploaded image into database laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image-uploading

I am having trouble uploading my image into database, everytime I try to upload it, the data send into the database is empty but my local disk is able to store the image and I don't know what to do. I think I might have done something wrong in the controller part

Controller:

```
public function store1(Request $request){

   $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);


   if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $image = $request->file('file');
        $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $size = $image->getClientSize();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);

        $userImage = new UserImage;
        $userImage->name = $name;
        $userImage->size = $size;
        //dd($userImage);
        $userImage->save;
}
```

table that I wanted to upload to:

```
Schema::create('user_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('size');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

[image]

Comment: before you get flags.. [read this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35431752/4648586). and also, please put the `binary` field away from your user table since it will slow down queries on most cases.. in short, the blob should be in another table..

Comment: @BagusTesa tks for replying, I forgot to update my question just now, that was the old one that I used, I just edited the question, please take a look, tks for the help

Comment: hmm, *uploading my image into database*, confusing indeed.. earlier you had `$table->binary('userImage');`. for now, have you tried @Miggy's suggestion yet? your code is missing `()`.

Comment: @BagusTesa sry for the confusion, because I saw a lot of post saying that it not a good thing to store images onto DB so I changed it to only store the name and size

Comment: well, its not really that bad, it only, you will need consider to alleviate the table burden by throwing the blob into another table. so queries to the main table is still easy for mysql to handle.

Comment: @BagusTesa ohh I see, I guess I kind of understand what you mean, thank you for teaching me :)

Comment: I'd suggest you to change the title to: "storing uploaded image *path* into database laravel" since you're not saving the binary, but the path string instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your posted code, you forgot setting the data for `user_id`. As I can see in your schema, it is not nullable so it should have a data.

Also, can you try putting `()` in your save like so :

```
 $userImage->save();
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you Miggy, I forgotten to put the bracket for save. It was such a careless mistake. Thank you so much for your help, I was kind stuck here for quite some time thinking where I was wrong

Comment: glad to help @blastme

Comment: Hi Miggy, sry to ask another question but do you know how to print out the image which is saved onto the public folder? I saw someone using this but I am not quite sure how to use it, "<img src="{{ asset('public/images/' . $model->image) }}"> --> to show in view"

Comment: you can use that @blastme. It will work. If not, you can create another question with the error and you can tag me ahead

Comment: Sure I will go create another question, erm but how do I tag you? Sorry I just started using SO few weeks ago and is still unsure about all the function

Comment: Sorry, i mean just comment here the question :). Dont worry im also new here. lol

Comment: Hi Miggy, sry for taking so long, I have just created the question could you help me take a look, tks a lot. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46922713/trouble-printing-out-image-from-public-folder-laravel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157415/discussion-between-miggy-and-blastme).