# Trouble printing out image from public folder laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image-uploading

I want to show the image that I had just uploaded and only show it to those who have uploaded it. For example, user table contain jack, Emily and John, so if jack were to upload a file the image will show directly under him, but I don't know how to do it?

This is how it look like now:
[image]

Controller: (how I store the image)

```
public function store1(Request $request){

   $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

   if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $image = $request->file('file');
        $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $size = $image->getClientSize();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);

        $userImage = new UserImage;
        $userImage->name = $name;
        $userImage->size = $size;
        //dd($userImage);
        $userImage->save();
}
```

view.blade.php

```
 @foreach ($data as $object)
    <b>Name: </b>{{ $object->name }}<br><br>
@endforeach
```

I saw people using this inside their blade.php, but I don't know what the $model is:

```
    <img src="{{ asset('public/images/' . $model->image) }}">
```

Upload.blade.php (this is my upload page where user will upload their image)

```
                        {{  csrf_field()  }}


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="imageInput" class="control-label col-sm-3">Upload Image</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="file" name="file">

        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
            </div>
          </div>
          </form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it.

You could either use `Eloquent` or using `query builder` of Laravel.

In your controller you should get all the images that the user uploaded.

`Query builder` approach :

```
//don't forget the namespace
`use DB;`

//in your function write this.
$images = DB::table('user_images')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'user_images.user_id')
        ->where('users.id', '=', $id) 
        ->get();

//use dd($images) to verify that the variable $images has data

//send $images in your view
```

in your view write a foreach loop like so:

```
@foreach($images as $image)
    <img src="{{ asset('public/images/' . $image->name ) }}"> 
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hi, tks for the reply. Do I have to create a one to one relationship with user and user image first before doing all this?

Comment: No sir. you don't have to create a relationship for that code to work.

Comment: Ohh I see, I keep getting undefined variable images, is it because my route is doing something wrong? "Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@Insert');"

Comment: I have multiple route which link back to /home, so will it like cause some error or anything? (eg of my other route, Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@getData')->name('home');)

Comment: can you use `dd($images)` in your controller.

Comment: public function Insert(){
    $images = DB::table('user_images')
        ->join('personal_info', 'id', '=', 'user_images.id')
        ->get();
        dd($images);
         //return view('test',compact('images'));
}

Comment: I can't seem to do a dd for some reason, it keep showing me the error

Comment: use this : `->join('personal_info', 'personal_info.id', '=', 'user_images.user_id')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157416/discussion-between-blastme-and-miggy).

Comment: Hi Miggy, could you help me take a look at my route and see if there is any problem?

Comment: Hi Miggy, I have put in the new code which work but no image being displayed could you help me take a look? Thanks

Comment: @blastme please see my response

Comment: so sorry for the late reply, I have updated my question to show that my database has data

Comment: @blastme your user_id is empty. thats why there is no data. in the query you are basically comparing the id of the profile table and the user id in your user images. Since there is no matching user_id to your id in profiles table it will return an empty array. From what i answered in your question before this. you forget to assign user_id in saving user_images

Comment: but I thought you said that there is no need for any relationship between tables so I had ignore the user_id part

Comment: Ahh sorry it was a misunderstanding. I thought that what you set is setting relationships between their models in laravel.

Comment: Erm maybe we continue this in chat? The comment here getting longer and longer

Comment: please see my response

Comment: sorry could you look at the chat @Miggy

Comment: Please figure it for youself. I did give you many help until now. Im here to help not give you all the answers

Comment: Yes, I know that but could you at least give me a hint for the next error? I have checked what I am doing is getting the id from table and by using compact I send it to the other view page. The route seem to be fine also and this 3 things are mostly the common mistake which I have checked online already. Yet I am still getting the undefined error, I tried to use dd but all it did was show an error