# Save a File To mysql Database From a form using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Good day Everyone, I'm less than 1 week old in laravel. I'm trying to save a Register CV page to MySQL database. Although my Form contains an upload file. While saving it to the database only the name of the file is saved the file itself isnt there. 
My code goes thus.
RegisterController.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\candidate;

use App\Http\Requests;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'surname' => 'required',
            'other_name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required', 
            'gender' => 'required',
            'field' => 'required',
            'qualification' => 'required',
            'resume' => 'required'
        ]);

        $candidates = new Candidate;
        $candidates->surname = $request->input('surname');
        $candidates->other_name = $request->input('other_name');
        $candidates->email = $request->input('email');
        $candidates->phone = $request->input('phone');
        $candidates->gender = $request->input('gender');
        $candidates->field = $request->input('field');
        $candidates->qualification = $request->input('qualification');
        
        $candidates->resume = $request->input('resume');
        $candidates->save();
        return redirect('/career')->with('response', 'Registered Successfully');
    }
}
```

2018_03_28_152114_create_candidates_table.php

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCandidatesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('candidates', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('surname');
            $table->string('other_name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('field');
            $table->string('qualification');
            $table->string('resume');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('candidates');
    }
}
```

then the form

```html
<form class="form-horizontal pv-20" action="/career/test-apply" method="POST" role="form">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

          .........
          ........
               

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2" for="resume">Upload Resume</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="resume" id="resume"         accept="application/pdf">                  
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-6" for="resume"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-curve btn-animated pull-right">Submit <i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>                  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: you need to save the file in a folder in your public folder, say for example in `uploads` folder and then you can save the file name or path in your database field

Comment: how would I do that @MehravishTemkar

Comment: Similar questions got answers here -> [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428876/how-to-store-and-retrieve-image-contents-from-the-database-using-laravel), [laravel.io](https://laravel.io/forum/02-17-2014-how-do-you-save-image-to-database-and-display-it-on-website)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store and retrieve image contents from the database using Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428876/how-to-store-and-retrieve-image-contents-from-the-database-using-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the file in the Public directory of your project. Then, you can just save the name of the file in MySQL database.