# Why the picture value is not uploaded into DB from laravel form?

Tags: laravel-5, image-uploading

I have a form for adding new profile. In the form, there is a file input field to enable user upload his/her picture to be saved in DB as its pathname to image saved in folder server.

However, my testing shows that it doesn't detected input field has image and doesn't go into  if ($request->hasFile('image')) statement loop. This is the form field for file upload.

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <label for="gambar" class="col-md-3 control-label">Gambar (Saiz gambar 250x300 pixels)</label>
              <div class="col-md-7">
                {!! Form::file('image', array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the controller function to upload the image:

```
    // **************************
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = $request->input('image');
        $photo = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destination = public_path() . '/images/';
        $request->file('image')->move($destination, $photo);
        $data = ['name' => $request->nama,
             'No' => $request->no_id,
             'nokp' => $request->no_kp,
             'dd' => $dd,
             'yy' => $request->yy,
             'SectionID' => $request->sections,
             'CategoryID' => $request->kategori,
             'OperasiID' => $request->pangkat,
             'AgamaID' => $request->agama,
             'JantinaID' => $request->jantina,
             'BangsaID' => $request->bangsa,
             'nolahir' => $request->no_surat_lahir,
             'kumdarah' => $request->kumdarah,
             'Picture' => $request->$photo,
             ];

        $itemregistrations = DB::table('itemregistrations')->insert($data);

        if($itemregistrations)
            return redirect('profil');
        else
            return redirect()->back()->withInput();

    } else {
    $data = ['name' => $request->nama,
             'No' => $request->no_id,
             'nokp' => $request->no_kp,
             'dd' => $dd,
             'yy' => $requestyy,
             'SectionID' => $request->sections,
             'CategoryID' => $request->kategori,
             'OperasiID' => $request->pangkat,
             'AgamaID' => $request->agama,
             'JantinaID' => $request->jantina,
             'BangsaID' => $request->bangsa,
             'nolahir' => $request->no_surat_lahir,
             'kumdarah' => $request->kumdarah,
             // 'Picture' => $request->$filePath,
             ];

    $itemregistrations = DB::table('itemregistrations')->insert($data);

    if($itemregistrations)
        return redirect('profil');
    else
        return redirect()->back()->withInput();

    }
```

Comment: Does your `Form::open` have `'files' => true`? look at https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html

Comment: it doesnt' have and i try to include it but still not success to insert the picture path to DB

Answer (score 1):

In your data array you target `'Picture' => $request->$photo,` and not `'Picture' => $photo,`

Also it looks like you are pulling just the extension look at the list below of some commands to use and when:

```
  //Display File Name
  $file->getClientOriginalName();

  //Display File Extension
  $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

  //Display File Real Path
  $file->getRealPath();

  //Display File Size
  $file->getSize();

  //Display File Mime Type
  $file->getMimeType();
```

To Uplaod a file do

```
$file = $request->file('image');
$file->move($destination, $file->getClientOriginalName());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Make sure your form have following attribute
enctype="multipart/form-data"
and use following laravel file upload code

       if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $is_file = true;
            $file_name = $input['image'] = time() . '.' . $request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $request->image->move(base_path() . '/assets/images/users/', $input['image']);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks.but I tried another solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428876/how-to-store-and-retrieve-image-contents-from-the-database-using-laravel as i need to store the image in blob type..