# Laravel does not display uploaded image

Tags: laravel

I'll need your help there, I have a form when I submit an image, it's working fine, but when I try to display the image on an another page, its display a white square (I can see that it's working because I can see the name of the image in the console). 
This is my app.blade.php :

```
   <div class="menu_connect_big_screen">
                <img src="{{Auth::user()->image}}"/>
                <p>{{Auth::user()->firstName}} {{Auth::user()->lastName}}</p>
                <a href="{{ url('/my_account') }}">Mon compte</a> | <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}">Se déconnecter</a>
            </div>
```

And this is my controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Auth;


class ProfilePictureController extends Controller
{
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $request = $request->All();

            User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)
                ->update(
                    [
                        'image' => $request['image']]
                );
            return redirect()->to('/')->with(['image-changed' => 'Photo de profil modifiée !']);
        }

}
```

I'm kinda new to laravel so any help would be thankful. 
Thank you.

Comment: What's the content of `Auth::user()->image` ?

Comment: did you use blob file type in your image column ?

Comment: @frogeyedman Yes I do :

Comment: @cbaconnier Its an image that I upload on a form

Answer (score 2):

If the image is stored in blob you should use base64 in your image tag like so;

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{base64_encode( Auth::user()->image )}}"/>
```

However, this is not specific to Laravel.

Comment: I don't know if it change something but its "longblob" not "blob"

Comment: To clarify: `blob` can only store as much as 16 KB of data. `mediumblob` up to 64 MB and `longblob` with 4 GB nearly the whole internet.

Comment: @Dan thanks for the clarification ahah, so even with base64 encoder I still have this problem

Comment: If you've used `blob` before and changed it so it can hold larger images, you might have to upload the image again.

Comment: @Dan Nah I stille used longblob and nothing change :/

Comment: @Bastien be sure to use your image type image/youreimgtype.

Comment: @frogeyedman if I want all type, but not only JPEG what do I do ?

Comment: @Bastien I would save the mime type from the file, you can get that from the request in laravel

Comment: It's still not working, I think maybe the problem is in the controller. I really don't know I'm kinda lost at this point *

Comment: @Bastien what is saved in the image column ?

Comment: @frogeyedman The image comes from a form that allowed the user to pick an image for his profile picture, and this is what appear in the column : [BLOB - 88 o]

Comment: i suggest reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428876/how-to-store-and-retrieve-image-contents-from-the-database-using-laravel

Answer (score 0):

For example user images stored in public/user_images directory

```
   <div class="menu_connect_big_screen">

       <img src="{{ asset('user_images/' . Auth::user()->image) }}" height="50px" width="50px">

       <p>{{Auth::user()->firstName}} {{Auth::user()->lastName}}</p>
       <a href="{{ url('/my_account') }}">Mon compte</a> | <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}">Se déconnecter</a>
   </div>
```