# How to upload images to the AWS s3 bucket from laravel-8 through postman?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, postman, laravel-8

i am very new to the AWS , i created s3 bucket in that and passing access keys region into my .env file and edited conig/filesystems.php and i write controller for posting my data ,my data is mixed type it's contains both binary and normal data so i am little bit confused which content type i have to use in postman(content-type=  ,inside headers).if i am using normal content-type=application/json and in body section i use raw at that time it's working but image is not uploaded into the s3 bucket , when i use content-type=multipart/mixed then i am getting following error ,please help me to fix this issue and how to upload images into s3 bucket from laravel through postman

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'image' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `books` (`image`, `price`, `title`, `quantity`, `author`, `description`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1, 2021-07-01 08:09:06, 2021-07-01 08:09:06)) in file C:\Users\VICKY\Desktop\8\laravel-bookstore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 692
```

`Books.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Books extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        // 'name',
        'image',
        'price',
        'title',
        'quantity',
        // 'ratings',
        'author' ,
        'description'  
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
   
    //inverse one to many
   public function user(){
       return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
   }
}
```

`BooksController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Books;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use App\Http\Resources\Books as BooksResource;
use App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate;

class BooksController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function DisplayBooks()
    {
        $books=Books::all();
        return User::find($books->user_id=auth()->id())->books; 
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function AddBooks(Request $request)
    {
        $book=new Books();
        //$book->name=$request->input('name');
        $book->image=$request->input('image'); 
if($request->hasfile('image'))
            {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $imageName=time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $filePath = 'images/' . $imageName;
            Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($file));
            }
        $book->price=$request->input('price');
        $book->title=$request->input('title');
        $book->quantity=$request->input('quantity');
       // $book->ratings=$request->input('ratings');
        $book->author=$request->input('author');
        $book->description=$request->input('description');
        $book->user_id = auth()->id();          
        $book->save();
        return new BooksResource($book);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function ShowBook($id)
    {
        $book=Books::findOrFail($id);
        if($book->user_id==auth()->id())
            return new BooksResource($book);
        else{
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'UnAuthorized/invalid id'], 401);
            }
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function UpdateBook(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $book=Books::findOrFail($id);
        if($book->user_id==auth()->id()){
            //$book->name=$request->input('name');
            $book->image=$request->input('image'); 
            $book->price=$request->input('price');
            $book->title=$request->input('title');
            $book->quantity=$request->input('quantity');
            //$book->ratings=$request->input('ratings');
            $book->author=$request->input('author');
            $book->description=$request->input('description');
            $book->save();
            return new BooksResource($book);
        }
        else
        {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => ' Book is not available ith id'], 404);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function DeleteBook($id)
    {
        $book=Books::findOrFail($id);
        if($book->user_id==auth()->id()){
            if($book->delete()){
                return response()->json(['message'=>'Deleted'],201);
            }
        }
        else{
            return response()->json([
                'error' => ' Method Not Allowed/invalid Book id'], 405);
        }
    }
}
```

`config/filesystems.php`

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'visibility'=>'public',
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Symbolic Links
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
    | `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
    | the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
    |
    */

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

];
```

`migration table`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateBooksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->integer('price')->unsigned();
            $table->text('title');
            $table->integer('quantity')->length(2)->unsigned();
           // $table->integer('ratings')->length(2)->unsigned();
            $table->string('author');
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('books');
    }
}
```

[image: How i am passing data in postman]
in Headers section  Authorization=Bearer token and content-type="multipart/mixed"

Comment: can you post the model of books here?

Comment: Hello @MahmoodHussain,  i posted books model now

Comment: It is not a good idea to store files as binary in the database you can either use local storage or as you have keys you can store in AWS. here is the tutorial on how to store files on AWS through laravel https://blog.devgenius.io/laravel-api-file-upload-to-aws-a8e87319b82e

Answer (score 0):

For simply storing images as binary in the database in laravel please refer to this :
[How to store and retrieve image contents from the database using Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428876/how-to-store-and-retrieve-image-contents-from-the-database-using-laravel#answer-35431752)

To Store in AWS

`composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3`

In our `.ENV` file edit the following:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=Access Key Id
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=Secret Access Key
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=Bucket Region
AWS_BUCKET=Bucket Name
```

Schema change `$table->binary('image');` to `$table->string('image');`

Controller

```
if($request->hasfile('image'))
{
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $imageName=time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
    $filePath = 'images/' . $imageName;
    Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($file));
    // After Image is uploaded make entry to database
}
```

Comment: Hello @MahmoodHussain, i want to upload my image from postman not manually uploading inside s3 bucket

Comment: I just mentioned the steps and thought you'll be able to write code. Of course, you'll do it from either postman or any other method like front-end

Comment: See updated answer and add merge code snippets with your code it should be go to go

Comment: Hello @Mahmood Hussain, i updated the code according what you suggested but it's getting same error

Comment: @Sravani you are not saving image name to your database just add `$book->name=$imageName;` and remove `$book->image=$request->input('image'); `

Comment: inside the bookscontroller na

Comment: ErrorException: Undefined variable: imageName in file C:\Users\VICKY\Desktop\8\laravel-bookstore\app\Http\Controllers\BooksController.php on line 36
i am getting this type of error after adding $book->name=$imageName;

Comment: before this line `$book->price=$request->input('price');` paste `$book->name=$imageName;`

Comment: still getting same error undefined variable

Comment: Place your code inside if($request->hasfile('image')) condition this would be helpful for debugging