# Return an Image from a Laravel 8 controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent

There are many questions that are similar to this one, but I've not seen any answer to what I am trying to do.
I have an image stored in MySQL, the column type is `mediumblob`, please don't lecture me on how this is a bad practice, I know.

Now, the question is how to serve/return the content of this image i.e the put the bytes into the response and send it to the client while attaching the proper headers?

**Edited**:

*But before serving the content of the image (blob), how to use eloquent to fetch the blob column?*

The code to fetch `image` column

```
function getImage($image_name) {
    $img = Image::select('image')->where('id', $image_name)->get();
    if (count($img) == 1) {
        return $img[0];
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Controller code

```
function getImageByName($img_name) {
    $img_ = $this->imagesService->getImage($img_name);
    return response($img_)->header('Content-type', 'image/png');
}
```

Comment: Does something not work? Any errors? Is the image/blob of type png? Does a route exist?

Comment: @bhucho no, some array returned from eloquent, thanks for mention this, I need to edit the question actually

Comment: @brombeer the route exists the problem is that I don't know how to get the content of the image from DB using eloquent and then send it to the client, In java this is a straightforward working with byte[] array

Comment: I would assume that you would need to return `$img[0]->image` to get the contents of the image column.. and then it is basic blob / base64 image displaying.. you could actually use `first()` instead of `get()` and use `$img->image` if it is going to return just one record.

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/a/35431752/9471283` this answer should help