# How can I store the images as Blob file in database using laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, blob, laravel-8

I want to store my images in database as a blob. not as a file path . How can I do that? I use Laravel .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store and retrieve image contents from the database using Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428876/how-to-store-and-retrieve-image-contents-from-the-database-using-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the job.

```
$path = $request->file('file')->getRealPath();    
$logo = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = base64_encode($logo);
$account->logo = $base64;
$account->save();
```

[Source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-save-image-as-blob)

Comment: Base64 adds processing overhead and increases storage requirements. Is it really needed?